# Jquery fadeIn() not working in my example

Tags: jquery

I have a div styled with .words which I want to substitute some text into and then fade in.  I have the following code:

```
$(".words").html("<p>" + "<pre>" + area + "</pre>" +"</p>").fadeIn(3000);
```

All works except there is no fadein  - the text appears immediately.  Don't see my mistake.  Please advise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this see if works : ( you need to hide the element first to make it fadeIn )

```
$(".words").html("<p>" + "<pre>" + area + "</pre>" +"</p>").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(".words").html("<p>" + "<pre>" + area + "</pre>" +"</p>").hide().fadeIn(3000);
```

---

You need to hide it before fading in